# Android Instrumentation pull test results/files from device

Tags: android-espresso, android-testing

During my attempt of porting a BDD library to Android JUnit runner I came to a deadlock how to properly pull the data back from the test run.

I presume I have 2 options:

1. Save the "BDD model results" on the device and pull them after the test run finishes

`//reportFile==/data/data/com.packagename.app/cache/jgiven
new ScenarioJsonWriter( model ).write( reportFile );`

2. Send the data back to instrumentation caller back during test runs so he saves it in some results output dir

**Questions**:

How to do 1. in a stable and proper way without changing app permissions to write to external storage, or adb vodoo (root, run-as etc)

Or how to do 2. properly which I would preffer, I can create a RunListener that would log these infos to am raw, or logcat, but still this does not feel right, how to write a gradle plugin that would hook up to these am raw results and save them to some file during test execution

```
public class JGivenTestRunListener extends InstrumentationResultPrinter {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "JGivenTestRunListener";

    /**
     * This value, if stored with key {@link android.app.Instrumentation#REPORT_KEY_IDENTIFIER},
     * identifies AndroidJUnitRunner as the source of the report.  This is sent with all
     * status messages.
     */
    public static final String REPORT_VALUE_ID = "AndroidJUnitRunner";
    /**
     * Used for sending scenario model json to the instrumentation for further processing
     */
    public static final String REPORT_KEY_JGIVEN_SCENARIO_MODEL = "scenariomodel";

    Bundle jgivenTestResult;
    private final Bundle mJgivenResultTemplate;
    public JGivenTestRunListener() {
        mJgivenResultTemplate=new Bundle();
    }

    @Override
    public void testRunStarted(Description description) throws Exception {
        mJgivenResultTemplate.putString(Instrumentation.REPORT_KEY_IDENTIFIER, REPORT_VALUE_ID);
        jgivenTestResult=new Bundle(mJgivenResultTemplate);
        super.testRunStarted(description);
    }

    @Override
    public void testFinished(Description description) throws Exception {
        ReportModel reportModel = ScenarioModelHolder.getInstance().getAndRemoveReportModel(description.getTestClass());
        String reportJson = new ScenarioJsonWriter(reportModel).toString();
        Log.e("REPORT",reportJson);
        jgivenTestResult.putString(REPORT_KEY_JGIVEN_SCENARIO_MODEL, reportJson);
        jgivenTestResult.putString(Instrumentation.REPORT_KEY_STREAMRESULT, "");
        sendStatus(0,jgivenTestResult );
        super.testFinished(description);

    }
}
```

Any suggestion how to solve this issue?